# How do i send twitter direct messages on behalf of logged in user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, oauth, devise

I have a twitter app with access level "Read, write, and direct messages"

I am using `omniauth-twitter` gem along with `devise` for letting users sign up and log into my site through twitter. All is fine till now.

It would be nice if the user is able to send direct messages to the his/her followers.

To fetch the list of followers I am using `twitter gem`. Now how do I let the user send the message he wants?

I have tried almost anything but all returns `This application is not allowed to access or delete your direct messages` error. This has been killing me for the past week

When I do `Twitter.verify_credentials` there is no error raised and a User object is returned. But when I call `Twitter.direct_messages` the above errors is raised. Am i missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** When I tried `Twitter.direct_message_create()` it worked like a charm! Would like to know as to why `Twitter.direct_messages` didn't work.

Comment: I have been as lucid as possible. Please tell me if i have to elaborate.

Comment: Check https://twitter.com/settings/applications to make sure that DM permissions are actually authorized. If not revoke and reauthorize.

Comment: Sorry.. but what do you mean by 'authorize'? The app's access level says "Read, write, and direct messages". Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. I just want to make sure the OAuth tokens the account has granted to the app actually include DM access. Sometimes an app will not have DM acces, OAuth tokens will get authorized then DM access gets added to the app settings but the OAuth token for the account doesn't have DM access authorized.

Comment: you were right.. thanks.. now how do i mark your comment as the answer? :)

Comment: You can't mark a comment as an answer but I created an answer from my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://twitter.com/settings/applications to make sure that DM permissions are actually authorized. If not revoke and reauthorize. Make sure the OAuth tokens the account has granted to the app actually include DM access. Sometimes an app will not have DM acces, OAuth tokens will get authorized then DM access gets added to the app settings and the OAuth token for the account doesn't have DM access authorized.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your update question:

> Update: When I tried Twitter.direct_message_create() it worked like a
>   charm. Would like to know as to why Twitter.direct_messages didn't
>   work.

```
Twitter.direct_message(id)
```

Is used to retrieve existing DMs, whereas:

```
Twitter.direct_message_create(user, text)
```

is used to send a DM.

See here: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/twitter/master/Twitter/Client/DirectMessages

Comment: The problem for me was that i had no permission to retrieve message but had permission to create one!

Answer (score 0):

As an update to @auxbuss's answer, the method has been renamed to:

```
Twitter.create_direct_message(user,text,options={})
```

The documentation has also moved:
http://rubydoc.info/github/sferik/twitter/master/Twitter/REST/DirectMessages.